# Int declared with &&, if else always returns true

Tags: c

This is a snippet I just made, whenever it runs, it always returns "And or statements can be declared in variables!", No matter what. I am fairly new to coding, so im not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
int test = 2 && 20;

if(test == 4 || 3){
    printf("\nAnd or statements can be declared in variables!");

}
else {
    printf("Looks like they cant.");
```

Comment: What did you expect that code to do?

Comment: i.e `(any_boolean_convertible_expression || 3)` will always be true.

Comment: So, I guess that means I need to brush up on my logical operators. So, is it not allowed to use logical operators in declarations?

Comment: Certainly it's allowed. You just have to understand how they work. The expression `2 && 20` evaluates to `1`, and that's the value stored in `test`. Were you expecting the conditional nature of the expression to be retained in `test`? BTW, `2 && 20` is an *expression*, not a *statement*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First in your assignment you have a AND operator, so you will only be able to assign FALSE or TRUE.

Then your if statement is not doing what you think it does! `==` has a higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `||` so it will get evaluated first like this:

```
int test = 2 && 20; // assign's TRUE

((TRUE == 4) || 3)  //->(FALSE || 3)
(FALSE || TRUE) -> TRUE
```

I think what you want is this:

```
(test == 4 || test == 3)
```

Also I think you want to assign a numeric int value to your int variable and not a AND operation.

FYI:

If you do your condition like this (Yoda condition):

```
if(4 == test)
```

You are better 'protected' against typos like this: `if(test = 4)`

Comment: Ok, so how would one give more than one value to int test? Is it possible?

Comment: You can *reassign* the value of any variable any number of times. When you *reassign* the value of a variable, the previous value gets overwritten by the new value.

Comment: @EddyHamilton I don't really understand what you mean with: *one give more than one value to int test?* Please be a bit more specific (Do you mean add numbers together and assign it or reassign a variable?)

Comment: The issue is my basic lack of skill, not your ability to understand or explain. I have come to a conclusion, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

```
if(test == 4 || 3)
```

This statement will **always** return true because `3`, being a *non-zero* number, will always behave as `TRUE`, and as `OR` operator returns `TRUE` if one or both of its operands are `TRUE`.

Change it to:

```
if (test == 4 || test == 3)
```

Moreover,

```
int test = 2 && 20;
```

will always assign the value 1 to `test`, because you are storing the result of the `AND` operator when both the operands are non-zero.

If you wanted to use the [Bitwise AND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0zec0b2.aspx) operator,

```
int test = 2 & 20; //A single ampersand represents BITWISE AND.
```

Answer (score 0):

The first statement you do:

```
int test = 2 && 20;
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
int test = ( 2 && 20 );
```

Here, you are not assigning int value, you are assigning result of boolean expression, which is either 0 or 1. So we can rewrite:

```
int test;
if ( 2 && 20 )
{
  test = 1;
}
else
{
  test = 0;
}
```

Now, the expression `(2 && 20)` is expanded into: `( ( 2 != 0) && (20 != 0))`

So, the very first expression in you code is:

```
int test;
if ( (2 != 0) && (20 != 0) )
{
  test = 1;
}
else
{
  test = 0;
}
```

I guess, `test` would always be `1`.

Now, the statement:

```
if (test == 4 || 3)
```

is converted into:

```
if ((test == 4) || ( 3 != 0))
```

So, whatever the `test` value is, the result is always `true` (`1`)

Comment: Detail: "you are not assigning int value" mis-leads.  The result of the `&&` operator _is_ type `int`.  So OP is assigning an `int` value, be it `0` or `1`.